# How to run GraphQL query not in component Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I need to pass source data using graphQl to cms config but when i try to use it i get an error
The GraphQL query in the non-page component "C:/Users/NikitaSeliverstov/Desktop/amblik/src/cms/cms.js" will not be run.
How can i run query in non page component?

Answer (score 0):

Currently impossible. Only places to run graphql queries is in a component or createPages in a gatsby-node api.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apollo client, try spinning up a client in a service class that you can call from your application. The apollo-link-http library will send a fetch request to your GraphQL API.

```
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createHttpLink({uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql", credentials: 'include'}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
            addTypename: false
    })
});
class dataService {
    async fetchData(){
    return await client.query({
        query: gql`query FETCH_DATA{
            fetchData{
                data1
                data2
                data3
             }
         }`,
     });
 }
```

Comment: I tried and it seems to  be working but only in develop because after build graphQL closes

Comment: You will need to change the URI to be wherever your GraphQL API is being hosted. It may differ between environments.